# Can not click on control

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'm using `AutoItX.Dotnet 3.3.14.5` [from here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoItX.Dotnet/) and this is my code:

```
var win = AutoIt.AutoItX.WinGetHandle(txtWindowTitle.Text);
if (win != (IntPtr) 0)
{
    var cont = AutoIt.AutoItX.ControlGetHandle(win, "&Next >");
    AutoIt.AutoItX.ControlClick(win, cont);
}
```

Everything works well and it will execute the control-click (it will return 1 as I know it clicked), but nothing will happen. I mean by Clicking on that button something should happen but no click will happen on it. Where Am I wrong?

Comment: Eh, what do you mean everything works well ... either it works well or not? Or are you saying that no exception is thrown? What is the expected outcome as yoou stated the ControlClick function is being called? Have you checked with ISpy making sure you have the right window handle and control handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running your application with admin rights.

```
ControlClick ( "title", "text", controlID [, button = "left" [, clicks = 1 [, x [, y]]]] )
```

Also, some windows app won't respond to `ControlClick` unless they are active/in focus.
Try this:

```
var win = AutoIt.AutoItX.WinGetHandle(txtWindowTitle.Text);
if (win != (IntPtr) 0)
{
    AutoIt.AutoItX.WinActivate(win);
    var cont = AutoIt.AutoItX.ControlGetHandle(win, "&Next >");
    AutoIt.AutoItX.ControlClick(win, "", cont);
}
```

Comment: @InsideMan I did note that the binary must be run with admin rights. That has nothing to do with autoitX. You need to set this in the IDE app settings so it compiles with requiring admin rights or just run the exe with admin rights